# не обрабатывается событие click() для динамической формы

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять как обработать событие нажатия на кнопку для формы которая уже имеет в своем скрипте обработчик, вот пример кода который не работает:

```
<script src="//static-login.sendpulse.com/apps/fc3/build/loader.js" sp-form-id="51ba1972c6eb9b18ad10ec65ebb8d3bd0bc33d574c7325ef88d2b86e5f2d666d"></script>
```

Javasqrip:

```
$('.sp-button').click(function(){
                alert('ok');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v0euyka5/3/

а тоже самое без внешнего скрипта работает https://jsfiddle.net/r451hwm2/1/

Comment: а если так : `$("window").on("click, ".sp-button", function(){...}")` вот так ...проверьте

Comment: @МаксимЛенский это не подходит, проблема, в том, что все события с загружаемой формой обрабатывает скрипт, который грузится с этой формой, как это обойти я не знаю

Comment: получилось сделать через addEventListener  https://jsfiddle.net/v0euyka5/34/

Answer (score 1):

получилось сделать через addEventListener jsfiddle.net/v0euyka5/34

Answer (score 0):

Нужно делегировать обработчик, если форма динамическая. Нужно устанавливать обработчик на родителя формы (в данном случае это div id='form-parent'), который присутствует на странице при ее загрузке.

Например: https://jsfiddle.net/r451hwm2/11/

```js
$('#show').on('click', function(){
 $(this).next().fadeToggle();
});

//Делегированный обработчик
$('#form-parent').on('click', '#submit', function(){
 alert('Делегированный обработчик сработал');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-parent">
  <button id='show'>Показать форму</button>
  <form action="" style="display : none">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" id='submit'>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: это не работает для моего кода, проблема в том, что все события click() с загружаемой формой обрабатывает js скрипт, который грузится с этой формой, как это обойти я не знаю

Comment: тогда `bind("click", function(){...})` попробуйте